# JNI FindClass can't find class which uses jar

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm working on a project where some Java functions must be called from C++ code using JNI. I've tried that with a simple Java class, but when I'm starting to use extra `.jar` in my Java project JNI's `FindClass` function can't find my class. I've done some research and read about `classpath` which is needed for compiling .java file if it uses extra libs, but `FindClass` returns `null` in that case. Here's basic structure of my code

```
JavaVMOption options[2];
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVM *jvm;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
long status;
jclass cls;
jmethodID mid;
jint square;
jboolean not;

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_my_java_class>";
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=<path_to_my_jar_file>";
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 2;
vm_args.options = options;
status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

if (status != JNI_ERR)
{
    cls = env->FindClass("package/ClassName"); //returns null while using jar
    if(cls != 0)
    {   
        //do some stuff
    }
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
else
    return -1;
```

Any ideas?

UPDATED:
I've also tried

```
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_my_java_class>;<path_to_jar>";

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_my_java_class>";
    options[1].optionString = "-classpath <path_to_jar>";
```

Comment: I do believe `java.library.path` is for *native* libraries (i.e. `.dll` or `.so` files) - jars (I think) should be added to `java.class.path`

Comment: @DrewMcGowen you mean that options second line must look like `options[1].optionString = "-Djava.calss.path=<path_to_my_jar_file>";`?

Comment: You can combine them into just the first option with the path separator character (';' in windows, ':' in unix).

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: Try `-classpath <paths_to_jars>` instead of `-Djava.class.path=`

Comment: No it didn't help either :(

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html has some examples. @nabroyan: Please update your question with your updated code, so we can see if we all talk about the same thing...

Comment: @DrewMcGowen you were right from the beginning. It was my mistake - <path_to_my_jar_file> was pointing to just a directory, meanwhile it must point to exactly the jar file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, that there were 2 problems

1) path_to_my_jar_file

This path must point to the jar file and not to the directory folder which contains it.

2) -Djava.library.path

Comments of Drew McGowen and answer of Stephen C were right - path to jar file must be like they said.

Answer (score 11):

I think that your mistake is that you are putting a JAR on the "library.path".  The library path is the path for finding native libraries ... not JAR files.

You should put the JAR file on the classpath; e.g.

```
    options[0].optionString = 
        "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_my_java_class>:<path_to_my_jar_file>";
```

(On Windows, use ";" as the classpath separator instead of ":".)

Comment: You're amazing. I kept on seeing the syntax ".:" but couldn't infer that the dot means the current directory for the Java classpath. You just saved my day; thanks a lot :-)