# JNI cannot find class from jar file

Tags: java, c++, jar, java-native-interface

When I use JNI interface to find class from jar file, it returns nullptr, but if I find class directly from .class file, it will success.
The following code will output `Failed`.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    JavaVM* jvm = nullptr;
    JNIEnv* env = nullptr;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    const char* jar_path = R"(-Djava.class.path=.;.\MyTest.jar)";
    options[0].optionString = new char[strlen(jar_path) + 1];
    memset(options[0].optionString, sizeof(options[0].optionString), 0);
    memcpy(options[0].optionString, jar_path, strlen(jar_path));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.nOptions = 0;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    delete[] options;
    if (rc != JNI_OK) {
        cout << "Error code : " << rc;
        cin.get();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << "JVM load succeeded: Version ";
    jint ver = env->GetVersion();
    cout << ((ver >> 16) & 0x0f) << "." << (ver & 0x0f) << endl;

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("MyTest");
    if (cls != 0) {
        cout << "Success";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed";
    }

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    cin.get();
}
```

`MyTest.jar` was in the runtime directory. `jar tf MyTest.jar` outputs:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
MyTest.class
```

MyTest.java codes as follow:

```
public class MyTest {
    private static int magic_counter=777;

    public static void mymain() { 
       System.out.println("Hello, World in java from mymain");
       System.out.println(magic_counter);
    }
}
```

If I replace MyTest.jar to MyTest.class. The `env->FindClass("MyTest")` will return a valid pointer.
How should I find class from jar file? Does anybody have any ideas?

I have tried the solutions from [find-java-class-in-jar-using-jni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212286/find-java-class-in-jar-using-jni) and [jni-findclass-cant-find-class-which-uses-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972438/jni-findclass-cant-find-class-which-uses-jar), but there is no help.

Comment: Try printing out the contents of the string your `jar_path` variable points to...

Comment: It prints `-Djava.class.path=.;.\MyTest.jar`.  If I make `const char* jar_path = "-Djava.class.path=.;MyTest.jar";`, it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

emm...it's my fault! I set `vm_args.nOptions = 0;`. It should be `vm_args.nOptions = 1;`. I can find class now.